# Creating teams, and adding users through team members

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

Trying to accomplish: Creating a team, and assigning users to that team. These users will be team members.

Some notes:

- multi-tenant application. Application can invite users, and users are part of the account. In my teams/new view I can
- In my teams/new view I can see all of the users that are part of my account. I can click on the checkbox next to the user I'd like to add to the team

Models:

**team.rb**

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account

  has_many :team_members, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :team_members
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :team_members
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_members
  has_many :teams, through: :team_members
end
```

**team_member.rb.rb**

```
class TeamMember < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Controller:

```
module Accounts
  class TeamsController < Accounts::BaseController
    before_action :set_team, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
      @teams = current_account.teams.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def new
      @team = current_account.teams.new
      @team_member = @team.team_members.build
    end

    def show
    end

    def create
      @team = current_account.teams.new(team_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @team.save
          @team.team_members.where(account_id: current_account.id, user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create

          format.html { redirect_to @team, notice: "Team was successfully created." }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @team }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @team.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    private

      def set_team
        @team = current_account.teams.find(params[:id])
      end

      def team_params
        params.require(:team).permit(:name, :account_id, team_members:[])
      end
  end
end
```

Views:
**teams/new.html.erb**

```
<section class="section">
    <%= render 'form', team: @team %>
</section>
```

**teams/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@team) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <form class="px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4 bg-white rounded">
    <div class="mb-4">
      <div class="w-full mb-4 md:mr-2 md:mb-0">
        <label class="block mb-2 text-sm font-bold text-gray-700" for="teamName">
          Name your team
        </label>
         <%= f.input :name, autofocus: true, class: 'w-full px-3 py-2 mb-3 text-sm leading-tight text-gray-700 border rounded shadow appearance-none focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline', label: false %>
       </div>
     </div>


     <div class="field">
       <%= f.label "Add users to team" %><br />
       <%= f.collection_check_boxes :team_members, current_account.users.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
         <div class="collection-check-box">
           <%= b.check_box %>
           <%= b.label %>
         </div>
       <% end %>
     </div>

   <div class="field">
    <div class="control">
      <%= f.button :submit, class: "w-full px-4 py-2 font-bold text-white rounded-full bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" %>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
<% end %>
```

A few more notes:

In my controller. You will notice I have a line in the create method, just below the save

```
@team.team_members.where(account_id: current_account.id, user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create
```

This does create a TeamMembers in my database for the current user. However, I would also like to add the users that I am selecting in my form to also be added as TeamMembers.

**Quick update**

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Accounts::TeamsController#create
TeamMember(#70366319660620) expected, got "" which is an instance of String(#70366253145620)

Parameters:

{"authenticity_token"=>"YCE3KxoOgFPSCc2H1olmfpKiorf2wY7XlCFJXisa5Va/Yi3z0fy2QCny45TB8rgUij9+1tV7U8CmtACK1cxgOg==",
 "team"=>{"name"=>"This is a test", "team_members"=>["", "5"]},
 "commit"=>"Create Team"}

NOTE, however, if I remove team_members:[] from the params, the record saves the current user into the database for Team Member

**Additional edit**

From the comments below, I am now using

```
def create
      team_members = User.find(team_params[:team_members])
      @team = current_account.teams.new(team_params.merge(users: team_members))

      respond_to do |format|
        if @team.save
          @team.team_members.where(account_id: current_account.id, user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create

          format.html { redirect_to @team, notice: "Team was successfully created." }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @team }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @team.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
```

and in the view, I have set include_hidden: false

Receiving the following error:

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Accounts::TeamsController#create
TeamMember(#70366305317040) expected, got "5" which is an instance of String(#70366253145620)

**Next update**

Using: @team = current_account.teams.new(team_params.except(:team_members).merge(users: team_members)

```
Started POST "/teams" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-02-09 17:29:59 -0500
17:29:59 web.1     | Processing by Accounts::TeamsController#create as HTML
17:29:59 web.1     |   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Pe+gDCggvkbeLcv0HiYr6LI52mnz89jtpVQSM9mf8mgIypqdEVn4yhlp6rEI9n4U7ijQHX4or9T8rPF5v8a5lw==", "team"=>{"name"=>"This is a test", "team_members"=>["5"]}, "commit"=>"Create Team"}
17:29:59 web.1     |   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
17:29:59 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/accounts/base_controller.rb:18:in `authorize_user!'
17:29:59 web.1     |   Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."subdomain" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["subdomain", "diplomat"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
17:29:59 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/accounts/base_controller.rb:6:in `current_account'
17:29:59 web.1     |   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
17:29:59 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/accounts/base_controller.rb:19:in `authorize_user!'
17:29:59 web.1     |    (0.9ms)  BEGIN
17:29:59 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/accounts/teams_controller.rb:23:in `block in create'
17:29:59 web.1     |   Team Create (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO "teams" ("name", "account_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "This is a test"], ["account_id", 2], ["created_at", "2020-02-09 22:29:59.577691"], ["updated_at", "2020-02-09 22:29:59.577691"]]
17:29:59 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/accounts/teams_controller.rb:23:in `block in create'
17:29:59 web.1     |    (0.5ms)  COMMIT
17:29:59 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/accounts/teams_controller.rb:23:in `block in create'
17:29:59 web.1     |   TeamMember Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "team_members".* FROM "team_members" WHERE "team_members"."team_id" = $1 AND "team_members"."account_id" = $2 AND "team_members"."user_id" = $3 ORDER BY "team_members"."id" ASC LIMIT $4  [["team_id", 37], ["account_id", 2], ["user_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
17:29:59 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/accounts/teams_controller.rb:24:in `block in create'
17:29:59 web.1     |    (0.3ms)  BEGIN
17:29:59 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/accounts/teams_controller.rb:24:in `block in create'
17:29:59 web.1     |   Account Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
17:29:59 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/accounts/teams_controller.rb:24:in `block in create'
17:29:59 web.1     |   User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
17:29:59 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/accounts/teams_controller.rb:24:in `block in create'
17:29:59 web.1     |   TeamMember Create (2.3ms)  INSERT INTO "team_members" ("account_id", "team_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["account_id", 2], ["team_id", 37], ["user_id", 2], ["created_at", "2020-02-09 22:29:59.609437"], ["updated_at", "2020-02-09 22:29:59.609437"]]
17:29:59 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/accounts/teams_controller.rb:24:in `block in create'
17:29:59 web.1     |    (0.7ms)  COMMIT
17:29:59 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/accounts/teams_controller.rb:24:in `block in create'
17:29:59 web.1     | Redirected to http://diplomat.lvh.me:5000/teams/37
17:29:59 web.1     | Completed 302 Found in 61ms (ActiveRecord: 10.0ms | Allocations: 13997)
17:29:59 web.1     | 
17:29:59 web.1     | 
17:29:59 web.1     | Started GET "/teams/37" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-02-09 17:29:59 -0500
17:29:59 web.1     | Processing by Accounts::TeamsController#show as HTML
17:29:59 web.1     |   Parameters: {"id"=>"37"}
17:29:59 web.1     |   User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
17:29:59 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/accounts/base_controller.rb:18:in `authorize_user!'
17:29:59 web.1     |   Account Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."subdomain" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["subdomain", "diplomat"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
17:29:59 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/accounts/base_controller.rb:6:in `current_account'
17:29:59 web.1     |   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
17:29:59 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/accounts/base_controller.rb:19:in `authorize_user!'
17:29:59 web.1     |   Team Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."account_id" = $1 AND "teams"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["account_id", 2], ["id", 37], ["LIMIT", 1]]
17:29:59 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/accounts/teams_controller.rb:38:in `set_team'
17:29:59 web.1     |   Rendering accounts/teams/show.html.erb within layouts/application
17:29:59 web.1     |   Rendered accounts/teams/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 4)
17:29:59 web.1     |   Rendered shared/_head.html.erb (Duration: 27.7ms | Allocations: 10259)
17:29:59 web.1     |   Rendered shared/_userselect.html.erb (Duration: 0.7ms | Allocations: 319)
17:29:59 web.1     |   Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 4.3ms | Allocations: 575)
17:29:59 web.1     |   Rendered shared/_notices.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 33)
17:29:59 web.1     |   Announcement Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "announcements".* FROM "announcements" ORDER BY "announcements"."published_at" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
17:29:59 web.1     |   ↳ app/helpers/announcements_helper.rb:3:in `unread_announcements'
17:29:59 web.1     |   Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (Duration: 9.8ms | Allocations: 843)
17:29:59 web.1     | Completed 200 OK in 61ms (Views: 43.8ms | ActiveRecord: 2.4ms | Allocations: 15711)
17:29:59 web.1     | 
17:29:59 web.1     |
```

Comment: Try to add in your `create` action: `team_members = User.find(team_params[:team_members]` and then: `@team = current_account.teams.new(team_params.merge(users: team_members)` I think it should work as well

Comment: This error because of empty value, you can remove it manually in the controller, or add `include_hidden: false` in your `f.collection_check_boxes .. include_hidden: false`

Comment: Receiving this error now: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Accounts::TeamsController#create
TeamMember(#70366336248820) expected, got "5" which is an instance of String(#70366253145620)

Comment: Now you can use code from the first comment :)

Comment: I am using the code from the first comment.

Comment: Try to use `@team = current_account.teams.new(team_params.except(:team_members).merge(users: team_members)`

Comment: I solved almost the same stuff a few months ago

Comment: If it will be worked for you, I propose you to change name of this collection of checkboxes and use parameter `users: []` instead of `team_members[]` then code from 1st comment will work for you, and it would be more clear

Comment: It did not post the user selected to the TeamMember. Posted the current_user, but not the user selected.

Comment: Possibly becuase I am not loading/adding the account_id on the team member that I am trying to add? IIRC, until I added the account_id: current_account.id on this: @team.team_members.where(account_id: current_account.id, user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create the current user would not be added as a Team Member.